# string passing by reference working fine else not in LCS problem

Tags: c++, dynamic, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

If I am passing the string reference in the function method then it is working fine, but if I am not passing it by reference then the test cases are failing with time limit exceeded.
Can anyone please tell me what am I missing ?

Working code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int lcsUtil(string& s1,int ind1,string& s2,int ind2,vector< vector<int>>&dp){
        if(ind1<0 || ind2<0) return 0;
        
        if(dp[ind1][ind2] != -1) return dp[ind1][ind2];
        
        if(s1[ind1] == s2[ind2])
            return dp[ind1][ind2] = 1 + lcsUtil(s1,ind1-1,s2,ind2-1,dp);
        
        else 
            return dp[ind1][ind2] = 0 + max(lcsUtil(s1,ind1-1,s2,ind2,dp),lcsUtil(s1,ind1,s2,ind2-1,dp));
    }
    int longestCommonSubsequence(string text1, string text2) {
        vector< vector<int> > dp (text1.size(),vector<int>(text2.size(),-1));
        return lcsUtil(text1,text1.size()-1,text2,text2.size()-1,dp);

    }
};
```

Not working code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int lcsUtil(string s1,int ind1,string s2,int ind2,vector< vector<int>>&dp){
        if(ind1<0 || ind2<0) return 0;
        
        if(dp[ind1][ind2] != -1) return dp[ind1][ind2];
        
        if(s1[ind1] == s2[ind2])
            return dp[ind1][ind2] = 1 + lcsUtil(s1,ind1-1,s2,ind2-1,dp);
        
        else 
            return dp[ind1][ind2] = 0 + max(lcsUtil(s1,ind1-1,s2,ind2,dp),lcsUtil(s1,ind1,s2,ind2-1,dp));
    }
    int longestCommonSubsequence(string text1, string text2) {
        vector< vector<int> > dp (text1.size(),vector<int>(text2.size(),-1));
        return lcsUtil(text1,text1.size()-1,text2,text2.size()-1,dp);

    }
};
```

Problem statment

https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-subsequence/

Comment: _" the test cases are failing"_ - do you get a reason for the failure? If it's because it exceeds a time or memory consumpion limit? Unrelated: Since you are not changing the strings, make them `const string&`

Comment: time limit exceeding.
for the test case -> https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/726846540/testcase/

Comment: Yes, I am not changing the string but should it be working for the second case,
I mean I don't see anything wrong in the 2nd code.

Comment: When you pass `std::string`s by value, you copy them every time. That takes time (and memory) and explains the limit exceeded. You could also have failed on exceeding the memory limit. When you pass them by reference, you don't make a copy of the string. You instead reference the already existing string.

Comment: oh got it copying each time can increase the time limit, I wasn't sure about this earlier, but now I can understand.
Thank you !!

Comment: @sandeepgaur It could, in fact, be the extra underlying calls to `malloc` (and `free`) which are tipping you over.  These tend to be expensive.

Comment: @PaulSanders if I am getting both the string in program arguments then how can I use malloc & free for these are you saying about 2d array if anything else could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Copying a `string` usually involves a call to `malloc` behind the scenes to store the copied characters.  There is a corresponding call to `free` when the string goes out of scope.  All of this is avoided if you pass the string by reference.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `std::string`s by value, like you do in your second example, you copy them every time. That takes time (and memory) and explains the limit exceeded. You could also have failed on exceeding the memory limit. When you pass them by reference, you don't make a copy of the string. You instead reference the already existing string.